# Determining whether the quotient $\mathbb{Q}[x] / \langle f(x) \rangle$ of a polynomial ring over a field is itself a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

I want to know whether $$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-1)$$ is a field or not. Is it as simple as determining if $x^3-1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q$?

But since it has roots , $x=1$ wouldn't this imply it is reducible and hence not a field? Or is there much more to it I am not considering?

Comment: Note: $[x-1][x^2+x+1]=[0]$, so this ring has a zero divisor and is therefore not an integral domain, much less a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Since we may factor the generator of the ideal $I := \langle x^3 - 1\rangle$ as
$$x^3 - 1 = (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1) ,$$
we see that in the quotient we have
$$((x - 1) + I)((x^2 + x + 1) + I).$$
These factors are zero divisors in $\Bbb Q[x] / I$, and hence that ring is not a field.

Comment: Thanks so is it not so correct to just set it equal to zero and see if it has a solution in the field?

Comment: If $f(x)$ has a root in $\Bbb K$, say, $r$, (and $\operatorname{deg} f > 1$), then we can write $f(x) = (x - r)g(x)$ for some $g$, and so $x - r + \langle f(x) \rangle$ is a zero divisor in $\Bbb K[x] / \langle f(x) \rangle$, which is hence not a field, so it's sufficient for $f$ to have a root, but it's not necessary. For example, if $\Bbb K$ is a field in which $-1$ has no square root, then $h(x) := (x^2 + 1)^2$ has no root but $\Bbb K / \langle h(x) \rangle$ is not a field, as $(x^2 + 1)$ is a zero divisor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right! Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ is a field if and only if $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$